# ng-change method not executing

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to pass the object selected in a  to update the data of another object. 
Here is the html

```
  <select id="categoryListBox"
                ng-model="category.selected"
                ng-change="updateCategory(category.selected)"
                ng-options="category._id as category.name for category in categories">
        </select>
```

This renders

```
<select id="categoryListBox" 
    ng-model="category.selected" 
    ng-change="updateCategory()" 
    ng-options="category._id as category.name for category in categories" 
    class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Test4</option>
    <option value="1">Test5</option>
 </select>
```

Here is my update function

```
$scope.updateCategory = function(){
    console.log('hi');
}
```

My problem is that right now when the selected item changes the updateCategory method doesn't fires. I would like for whenever the option selected in the `<select></select>` changes that my $scope.updateCategory method fires. It would also be awesome if I could pass the category selected to this method.

Update here is the my initalization which populates the array categories

```
$scope.init = function (){
            console.log('dfakjsdhf');
            console.log(apiUrl);
            $scope.category = {};
            $scope.subcategory = {};
            //$scope.categories = {_id: 1, name:'test'};

            $http({ method: 'GET', url: apiUrl + '/categories'}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.categories = data;
                    console.log($scope.categories);

                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('error');
                });


        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass the category.selected in your function. In your js controller it will be there in your scope, just use it in your updateCategory() function.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulr/9LG96/)

Html:

```
<select id="categoryListBox"
            ng-model="category.selected"
             ng-change="updateCategory()"
            ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories">
    </select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.updateCategory = function(){
    alert($scope.category.selected);
}
```

Comment: the console.log(hi); isn't showing up when the parameters are remove from both functions in the html and controller

Comment: @AustinDavis check the JSFiddle I added, in your question I still see the html passing selected category but the function doesnt have any input.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your ng-model from `category.selected` to something else. As per my understanding, In your code there is an ambiguity between ng-options *category* and ng-model *category*

```
<select id="categoryListBox"
            ng-model="categorymodel"
            ng-change="updateCategory(categorymodel)"
            ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories">
    </select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LG96/4/)